# can not use spaCy models in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pycharm, spacy

I am trying to use a spacy 'en' model in PyCharm

to run this code:

```
import spacy
    nlp= spacy.load('en')
    doc=nlp(u'I am trying to learn natural language processing for chatbots')

for token in doc:
    print(token.txt,token.pos)
```

how ever, I tried to do this command in pycharm to run the model:

```
"/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 9/Graduation Project/Studying Ch2/venv/bin/python" "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 9/Graduation Project/Studying Ch2/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 9/Graduation Project/Studying Ch2/main.py", line 2, in <module>
nlp= spacy.load('en')
  File "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 9/Graduation Project/Studying Ch2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 30, in load
return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/Users/zahraaal-nemer/Desktop/University/Level 9/Graduation Project/Studying Ch2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and I tried to apply this code:

```
FULL_PATH_TO_PYTHON_INTERPRTER -m spacy download en
```

as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -m spacy download en
```

the output of running the python3 -m spacy download en on anaconda terminal:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 14 07:19:49 on ttys000
. /Users/zahraa-maher/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate    /Users/zahraa-maher/opt/anaconda3; 
(base) zahraa-maher@Zahraas-MacBook-Pro ~ % . /Users/zahraa-   maher/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate /Users/zahraa-   maher/opt/anaconda3; 
(base) zahraa-maher@Zahraas-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 -m spacy download en
Requirement already satisfied: en_core_web_sm==2.3.1 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-   models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.3.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (2.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc==7.4.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.4.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=1.0.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (4.47.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (49.2.0.post20200714)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.4.0,>=2.3.0->en_core_web_sm==2.3.1) (2020.6.20)
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
✔ Linking successful
/Users/zahraa-maher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-   packages/en_core_web_sm -->
/Users/zahraa-maher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-   packages/spacy/data/en
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')
```

and here is when I run echo ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8:

```
(base) zahraa-maher@Zahraas-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8 
./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8
```

and after I did that, I run this code on py charm:
import spacy

```
import spacy 
nlp= spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

and the output was:

```
"/Users/zahraa-maher/Desktop/study nlp/nlp codes/bin/python" /Users/zahraa-maher/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zahraa-maher/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    spacynlp= spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
  File "/Users/zahraa-maher/Desktop/study nlp/nlp codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/Users/zahraa-maher/Desktop/study nlp/nlp codes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

which still not works and shows the same error, and I am not sure of the python interpreter path

and I don't know how to get the right one to let it work in pyCharm, I used the one I have shown for you as I found by a method when I researched before, but it does not work

could someone help me to solve this issue and let it work on pyCharm?

I am using Mac OS and it has python 2 installed by default, and I also installed python 3.8 with anaconda

and I want to use the models inside the pycahrm or any IDE but not in Jupyter notebook

Comment: What output did you get from `python3 -m spacy download en` command?

Comment: Are you activating the anaconda environment before attempting to download the model files?

Answer (score 1):

After the details added, it seems that you are downloading the model for a `base` anaconda environment whereas when you run your code from PyCharm you are using a virtual environment from `/Users/zahraa-maher/Desktop/study nlp/nlp codes` directory which has nothing to do with the anaconda one.

I suggest that in PyCharm you run system command line and rerun download of the model:

```
python3 -m spacy download en
```

PyCharm is going to ensure you are executing this in the context of proper Python environment.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still not work and the same error.

Comment: Do you have different versions of python installed, and are you using the same one? What is the output of the download command described in this post? After the download, what is the output of running `python -m spacy validate` (or `python3` depending on what you're using)? Could you add all of this information to your original post?

Comment: I have did that

Comment: @zmn: It would be great if you could add information about the version of SpaCy. Also, please add output of `python3 -m spacy download en` and `echo PYTHONPATH` from the terminal?

Comment: I have done that, please see the new updates in the post